# Efficient insertion of deterministic acyclic finite state automaton (DAFSA) into a full-text search index?

Tags: suffix-trees

I have a problem where I can easily construct a set of deterministic acyclic finite state automata (DAFSA) and I need a full-text search index, e.g. a suffix tree/array, over all the words encoded by these automata.

Is there an efficient algorithm for this? By *efficient* I mean that the complexity must not depend on the on the total number of words encoded in the DAFSA which may get very large. Consider the following example:

```
(all edges are directed from left to right)

  a1 --- a2 ... a{n-1} --- an
 /   \ /               \ /   \
S     X                 X     T
 \   / \               / \   /
  b1 --- b2 ... b{n-1} --- bn
```

In this example there are $2^n$ distinct paths from `S` to `T`, e.i. if the nodes were labelled with characters it would be an DAFSA encoding $2^n$ words. Still, the number of vertices is just $2(n+1)$ and the number of edges $4n$.

Comment: (If you want *any state of the art support for full text search* (as it seems in `need a full-text search index, e.g. a suffix tree`), try and not use *suffix tree* in the title and the request for an algorithm. `complexity must not depend on the [DAFSA's] number of words` looks restrictive given the interdependency with number of states & symbols.)

Comment: I think you also need to define efficiency for search queries. Otherwise simple simulation of NFA with the same diagram but all states as initials would satisfy your description.

Comment: @DmitriUrbanowicz Granted. For any index, I would expected $O(log n)$ or better where $N$ is the size of the full text.

Answer (score 0):

There is (probably) no such algorithm. At least, for suffix tries it is not possible:

For every word encoded by the DAFSA there must be at least an end-of-word marker in the suffix tree. Thus, the construction takes at least $\Omega(N)$ where $N$ is the number of words encoded by the DAFSA.

This argument cannot be extended to any kind of search index because it may employ some kind of compression – like the DAFSA does.

Comment: Apparently, any DFA functioning as a full-text index for DAFSA has exponentially many states in the worst case.

Comment: That's true iff you want the DFA to discern between different words of the DAFSA, e.i. there exists an accept state for every word. Otherwise – I think – every DAFSA is a DFA by definition.